# Rails url helper with custom params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

There is the following code:

```
before { get user_posts_path(user) }
```

As you can see I'm trying to make a 'GET' request, but this helper (user_posts_path) doesn't work, because I need to use user.login insteaf of user.id for this helper. How can I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: is this code in a spec?can you provide more code and context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If user.login is just a value, you should be able to use the helper as

```
user_posts_path(user.login)
```

If you only ever need user.login in the url (instead of id), you can override the method to_param on User to return the login instead of the id. The ActiveRecord::Base version is deprecated (moved to another module), but this page lists the other versions:

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/to_param